# Regex to remove "&#160",<br> and <p></p> Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the tags and spaces: `"&#160"`,`<br>` and `<p></p>` from my content.

I tried below removing p and br tags :

```
let Desc=  response[i].Description.replace(/<p><br[\/]?><[\/]?p>/g,""');
```

but it is not removing br and p tags .

Could anyone pls help on how to remove tags and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var Desc = $(response[i].Description).text();
```

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function allows to extract text content from HTML.

If this doesn't work for you then try any of below solutions:

1. [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)
2. [Strip HTML Tags in JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/)

Comment: Hi @Swetha have you tried this solution? Is it working for you?